# Error while importing project to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have instaled all the tools evreything is ok but i get this ereur
[this is it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22ifl.png)

this is my sdk tools 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rkI4.png)

Comment: Don't posts images to your question. Just copy and paste text, code, logs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple versions of Android Build Tools installed. Uninstall all of them, including the latest version. Then reinstall the latest version and you should be fine. If you want multiple versions of the build tools, consider switching to Android Studio.